# Article "the" or not

Tags: articles

Do not need the article "the" before the word "songs"?

Here mean precisely the songs from this album and not any other.

[image]

Comment: Your context is a bad example, because it's effectively "headlinese", which has its own peculiar standards of "reduced" syntax. The big giveaway being that ***there is no verb*** - a "valid sentence" for normal contexts would be *All [the] songs **are** written by Tyler*, where the article is completely optional. But in practice the article wouldn't normally be included, in headlinese ***or*** "normal" contexts. Consider, for example, [*All roads lead to Rome*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_roads_lead_to_Rome), which ***never*** includes an article.

Comment: If this *weren't* headlinese, it wouldn't use *the* anyway. It would be *All **these** songs **were** written . . .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can regard this as "title abbreviation", the kind of omissions which are common in headlines, titles and so on.  As it is a label on an object, implicitly it means the words and music in this object.

On records, one of the most common forms is "words by X music by Y", but you will find many, many, others, including very playful variations.

Comment: In OP's *exact* context (which looks like "album cover art" to me) it would be *very* unusual to include the article, so it's not really "optional" at all. But if it occurred in some more "normal" text sequence, such as a review of the album (where we'd more or less *require* a verb to be present anyway, unlike the cited example), it really would be optional.